# Filtering on the count with the Django ORM

Tags: django, orm, aggregate

I have a query that's basically "count all the items of type X, and return the items that exist more than once, along with their counts". Right now I have this:

```
Item.objects.annotate(type_count=models.Count("type")).filter(type_count__gt=1).order_by("-type_count")
```

but it returns nothing (the count is 1 for all items). What am I doing wrong?

Ideally, it should get the following:

```
Type
----
1
1
2
3
3
3
```

and return:

```
Type, Count
-----------
1     2
3     3
```

Comment: I could, but the relevant bit is just that there's an "Item" model with a "type" field...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order to count the number of occurrences of each type, you have to group by the `type` field. In Django this is done by using `values` to get just that field. So, this should work:

```
Item.objects.values('group').annotate(
     type_count=models.Count("type")
).filter(type_count__gt=1).order_by("-type_count")
```

Comment: yea - that's right, but use `type` instead of `group` :) it will return something like: [{'type': u'X', 'type_count': 2}] - why didn't I said that earlier :)

Comment: I think you meant "type" there instead of "group", it *did* work when I did this without the __gt part, but with the __gt part it just throws "dict object has no attribute type_count", which tells me that it's trying to access it as an column...

Comment: That's strange - I've checked it and it works like a charm. Btw. when it's saying about no type_count attr in dict it means the dict generated by aggregate - it does not try to acces it like a column. The results should be like I wrote above. Check it in django shell to be sure.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I forgot it was turned into a dictionary and was trying an attribute lookup. It works very well now, thank you! I'll leave this answer as correct because I can't split it in two :(

Answer (score 3):

It's logical error ;)

`type_count__gt=1` means `type_count > 1` so if the `count == 1` it won't be displayed :)
use `type_count__gte=1` instead  - it means `type_count >= 1` :)

Comment: yea but you said the count is 1 for each one - that's the reason why nothing is displayed :)

Comment: There are duplicate types, yet the count for everything is 1. This is wrong, but I don't know why the count isn't the correct one.