# Django annotate count with filter condition as count

Tags: django, django-models

I need to get the duplicate entries of field "title" in model "Mymodel"  where the count is greater than 2. So that I can remove all the duplicates from Mymodel.

I am trying to execute the query as below, but it throws exception "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'lookup'"

```
movies = Mymodel.objects.values('title')\
            .annotate(title_count=Count('title'), distint=True)\
            .filter(title_count__gt=2)
```

Equivalent raw sql query

```
SELECT count(title) as num_title, title from app_mymodel group by title having count(title) > 2;
```

I found similar question here, [Filtering on the count with the Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795449/filtering-on-the-count-with-the-django-orm) But it not working for me.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Note: `distinct`, not `distint`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try similar query without `distinct`, as I don't think you can pass that to `annotate`.

```
movies = Mymodel.objects.values('title')\
        .annotate(title_count=Count('title'))\
        .filter(title_count__gt=2)
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I tried different ways, but i did not try this way :-)

Answer (score -4):

It throws exception AttributeError because the **Count** function have *distinct* argument, but not *distint*.